# views relationships not working for me in views 3.7

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to create a block with related posts by taxonomy term, however, i cannot setup views relationships properly. What have i done (url, where i have found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454507/creating-list-of-similar-nodes-in-drupal-7-views-3):

```
   Create a block view
    Add Contextual filter -> Content: Nid -> Provide default value -> Content ID from URL
    Add Relationship -> Content: Taxonomy terms on node -> specify the appropriate vocabulary
    Add Relationship -> Taxonomy term: Content using vocabulary as specified above -> Check off Require this relationship
    Turn on Views aggregation
    Assuming you are listing title only, edit the title field to use the Relationship you set up in #4 above.
    Add new sort criteria of Content: Nid. In aggregation settings, select Count. Use relationship from #4 and sort descending
    Add Contextual filter -> Content: Nid -> Use relationship from #4 -> Provide default value - Content ID from URL -> Scroll down and expand "More" then check "Exclude" to remove current node from the view
```

When i add relations i cannot use them on my node:title, there's just no option to choose these relations i have created. Any ideas?